# Failed to stage application, with error code 170001

Tags: cloud-foundry

App deployment into Pivotal Cloud Foundry is failing. Find below staging error  log. I am guessing download of buildpack could be failing.

#### log of 'cf push' command:

Creating app gs-serving-web-content in org DEV / space Project-1 as abc.xyz...
OK

Creating route gs-serving-web-content.cf.myorg.com...
OK

Binding gs-serving-web-content.cf.myorg.com to gs-serving-web-content...
OK

Uploading gs-serving-web-content...
Uploading app files from: gs-serving-web-content-0.1.0.jar
Uploading 546.7K, 89 files
Done uploading
OK

Starting app gs-serving-web-content in org DEV / space Project-1 as abc.xyz...
FAILED

**Server error, status code: 400, error code: 170001, message: Staging error: failed to stage application:
Error downloading: Response status: unknown, Error: Errno::ECONNREFUSED**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check if enough stagers are there. I believe its a memory issue. just try to increase memory in you cf instance.